# jquery - Slide Toggle

Tags: jquery

I haver the following HTML:

```
<div class="community-topic">
  <h2><b>Ask</b> a Question</h2>
  <p class="ask">+</p>
    <div class="addtitle">
      <p>Give your Question a great title</p>
        <form name="input" action="submit.php">
         <input id="title" type="text" name="title" />
         <input id="go" type="submit" value="Go" />
        </form> 
       <a href="discuss.php?style=question">See more questions</a>
     </div>
```

Then the following jQuery:

```
$('.ask').toggle(function() {
    $(this).text('-').next('.addtitle').slideDown('fast');
}, function() {
    $(this).text('+').next('.addtitle').slideUp('fast');
});
```

I also want the `.toggle` function to happen when the `<h2>` his clicked.

How can adjust the above jQuery to include this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach a click handler to the `h2` that clicks the `<p>` like this:

```
$('.ask').toggle(function() {
    $(this).text('-').next('.addtitle').slideDown('fast');
}, function() {
    $(this).text('+').next('.addtitle').slideUp('fast');
}).prev('h2')​​​.click(function() {
    $(this).next().click();
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pGHDu/), this makes a click on the `<h2>` trigger a `click` event on the `.ask`, firing its [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.  It's important to do this instead of using both in the selector because the toggle's state is *per element*, so to keep them in sync you only want it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
$('.community-topic h2').toggle(function() {
    $(this).next('.addtitle').slideDown('fast');
}, function() {
    $(this).next('.addtitle').slideUp('fast');
});
```

Comment: `.next()` only finds the *very* next element *if* it matches the selector, to get `.addtitle` you'd actually need `.nextAll('.addtitle:first')` :)